# DataGridCell style, how to reference the cells value to bind to a converter?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a converter that takes a decimal value and converts it to a brush (red for negative and black for positive input).  I also created a style that I want to apply to all `DataGridTextColumn` that will take decimal values.  If I inline the style for each DataGridTextColumn I can simply specify the related property on the Datacontext in the binding expression.  However I don't want to inline the style and simply have it as a resource, that way I can set the CellStyle to the resource.  The problem is I don't know what to put in the Binding of the value for the Foreground property.  I want to be able to bind it to value that the cell to which it's being applied is bound to.

Here is what I have:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- This converter takes a decimal value and returns a brush -->
        <conv:NumericValueBrushColorConverter x:Key="NumericValueBrushColorConverter"></conv:NumericValueBrushColorConverter>

        <Style x:Key="CurrencyStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{Binding WhatGoesHere, Converter={StaticResource NumericValueBrushColorConverter}}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>             


    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CashReport}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beginning Cash Available" Binding="{Binding BeginningBalance, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CurrencyStyle}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ending Cash Available" Binding="{Binding EndingBalance, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CurrencyStyle}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Update #1**

As per Jefim's suggestion I should attempt to use the ElementStyle as it works directly on the rendered TextBlock as opposed to (CellStyle) the content control (whatever that is) that holds the TextBlock.

```
    <Style x:Key="CurrencyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource NumericValueBrushColorConverter}}"/>
    </Style>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CashReport}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beginning Cash Available" Binding="{Binding BeginningBalance, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CurrencyStyle}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ending Cash Available" Binding="{Binding EndingBalance, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CurrencyStyle}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This seems to work, however when I track my converter's Convert method it seems to fire about 28 times or so with empty value being passed to the Convert method.  After that all values flow as expected.  When the grid renders everything looks right, there are no empty cells.  What executes my converter the first 20+ times without values?

Update #2
I believe my current issue is unrelated to the original question so I moved it out to: [IValueConverter executes more times than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433271/ivalueconverter-executes-more-times-than-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and probably should) use the `ElementStyle` / `EditingElementStyle` properties - they will allow you to style the `TextBlock` and `TextBox` that are within the cell. E.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="CurrencyStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource NumericValueBrushColorConverter}}"/>
</Style>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CashReport}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beginning Cash Available" Binding="{Binding BeginningBalance, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CurrencyStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ending Cash Available" Binding="{Binding EndingBalance, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CurrencyStyle}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**UPDATE**

Updated the code to the same as in the question's update #1 so that people who look at the answer would see the correct version of code (by e36M3)

Comment: This doesn't work because there is no "ElementStyle" property on a DataGridCell.  However point taken on using the Elementstyle of a DataTextColumn so I made the adjustment and update my original post.  I still have an issue with why the converter fires several times with empty value before the real values start coming through.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think that most probably you are setting the properties multiple times (e.g. you init the values of those properties with zeroes). Otherwise it is hard to tell without additional info. Try inspecting the stack trace.

Comment: Jefim I just updated my original post with exactly what I'm doing.  Maybe that will be of any help.

Comment: Jefim, I think my current issue is unrelated to the original question so I posted another question for that.  I will consider this answer the correct answer.  BTW I think XAML complains if you use TargetType="DataGridTextColum", it however worked the way I posted it in my update.

Comment: Well, I am glad you figured it out eventually. Good to know. Same goes for the link in your update #2. And yes, XAML would complain about DataGridTextColumn since the target type must be derived from FrameworkElement and DataGridTextColumn is derived from DependencyObject and I completely forgot about that.