# IValueConverter executes more times than expected

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, ivalueconverter

I have a converter that takes the text from a TextBlock that makes up a DataGridCell and converts it to a red or black brush depending if the value is negative or positive.  However the converter executes more times than there are items in the datasource of the grid.  For example if I simply bind a collection that contains 1 object, the converter executes 2 times.  The first time the `value` parameter is an empty string, the second time it actually contains the value that I would expect.  If I add more objects to the list, the number of initial "empty" executions grows.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:NumericValueBrushColorConverter x:Key="NumericValueBrushColorConverter"></conv:NumericValueBrushColorConverter>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CashReport}" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beginning Cash Available" Binding="{Binding BeginningBalance, StringFormat={}{0:C}}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"  Value="Right" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource NumericValueBrushColorConverter}}"/>      
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid> 


[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
internal class NumericValueBrushColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    static int i = 0;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        i++;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue)) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        if (strValue.StartsWith("("))
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first the TextBlock in the grid row is created and thus empty (= first execution) and then the content is bound to the value of the current item (= second execution). Nothing wrong here.

Comment: Indeed, just check if string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) and return if true.

Comment: What is interesting is the fact that if I bind 315 items to the grid, there are only 27 empty calls.  Wouldn't it be the same number as there are items (rows) in the bound list?

Comment: That is strange and I don't have an explanation for it, sorry.

Comment: Only the viewable items run the bindings.

Comment: Josh I am not entirely sure what that means.  If I have 315 objects, of which I'm only displaying one property to keep it simple.  All the properties are decimal so they all have values even if it's 0, I would expect 315 empty calls and 315 with values as per the original answer.

Comment: @e36M3: To optimize performance WPF only evaluates the bindings of objects currently visible on the screen. I am pretty sure, that your grid only shows 27 items at a time and you will have to scroll the grid to view more items. That's what Josh meant with "viewable".

Answer (score 2):

I expect @Daniel Hilgarth is right. You should check the value in your converter before trying to convert. You can return Binding.DoNothing when you don't want the binding to run.